# FOREIGN_KEY constraint exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities

I have an asp.net application with a c# code-behind, connected to an SQL db with linq-to-entities... When I attempt to 'SaveChanges()' on the following code I get an exception (listed below). Any thoughts on what is up?

```
private void setNewRide(long newRideID, int carNum)
        {
            handleCompletedRide(carNum);

            using (myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
            {
                Vehicle assignedCar = myEntities.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(car => car.CarNum == carNum);
                Ride newRide = myEntities.Rides.FirstOrDefault(ride => ride.identity == newRideID);

                if (assignedCar != null && newRide != null)
                {
                    vs_CurrentRideId = newRide.identity; //Save current ride to ViewState
                    vs_CarStatus = assignedCar.Status; //Save old status to ViewState

                    assignedCar.Status = "EnRoute";
                    assignedCar.CurrPassengers = newRide.NumPatrons;
                    assignedCar.StartAdd = newRide.PickupAddress;
                    assignedCar.EndAdd = newRide.DropoffAddress;
                    assignedCar.CurrentAdd = newRide.DropoffAddress;

                    assignedCar.Rides.Add(newRide);

                    newRide.TimeDispatched = DateTime.Now;
                    newRide.WaitTime = (((DateTime)newRide.TimeDispatched) - ((DateTime)newRide.TimeOfCall));
                    newRide.AssignedCar = carNum;
                    newRide.Status = "EnRoute";

                    myEntities.SaveChanges(); //EXCEPTION HERE!
                    SelectCarUP.DataBind();
                    SelectCarUP.Update();                    
                }
            }
        }
```

THE EXCEPTION:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_Rides_Vehicles\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"CWIS29RamRideOps\", table \"dbo.Vehicles\", column
>   'Identity'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

THE DB:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
assignedCar.Rides.Add(newRide);
```

is translated as SQL-INSERT - while you already have a record with the same ID. Decide what you want to do: insert a new ride (in which case you should NULLify the id of newRide), or update it (in which case you should just comment that line out; changes will be saved).

Comment: I am attempting to update. Sounds like a reasonable argument..but I removed the line and still get the same exception.

Comment: I'm sorry; it's too late; I told you something that makes no sense; please ignore. I confused `assignedCar` with `myEntities`. Unfortunately, I cannot think of anything right now.

Comment: How about this line: `newRide.AssignedCar = carNum;`. I think it's redundant to `assignedCar.Rides.Add(newRide);`. Try to comment it out and see what happens. If that's still not it, instead of that (assign the Id of assignedCar to newRide.AssignedCar), assign the complete assignedCar to newRide.WhateverTheAssignedCarObjectIsButNotCarId. I hope you understand. Try that.

Comment: Yup you got it, forgot about a change I made a change in the db where the carNum assignment was now redundant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
newRide.TimeDispatched = DateTime.Now;
newRide.WaitTime = (((DateTime)newRide.TimeDispatched) - ((DateTime)newRide.TimeOfCall));
newRide.AssignedCar = carNum;
newRide.Status = "EnRoute";

assignedCar.Status = "EnRoute";
assignedCar.CurrPassengers = newRide.NumPatrons;
assignedCar.StartAdd = newRide.PickupAddress;
assignedCar.EndAdd = newRide.DropoffAddress;
assignedCar.CurrentAdd = newRide.DropoffAddress;
assignedCar.Rides = newRide; // Your First Change here

myEntities.SaveChanges();
```